# JDBC result variable returns a value with braces and equal character

Tags: sql-server, groovy, jmeter

I'm trying to assert the data coming from variable in JDBC PostProcessor(using SQL server) with JSON response, the data is coming from JSON as expected but the problem is the one that coming from Database has braces and an equal character, so the test fails

The value coming from DB --> {=598}

The expected one(from JSON) --> 598

**groovy code:**

```
import groovy.json.JsonOutput
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper();

//parsing incoming json
def response = jsonSlurper.parseText(prev.getResponseDataAsString());

//getting actual json
def AssessmentId_JSON = JsonOutput.toJson(response[0].AssessmentId);

// Getting "data" variable from DB query(getObject() method returns ArrayList data type)
def valueFromDBQuery = vars.getObject("data"); 

//Converting from arraylist to string (if list has one element)
String AssessmentId_DB = valueFromDBQuery[0]; 

log.info ("The Value is: " + AssessmentId_DB);
log.info ("It should be: " + AssessmentId_JSON);
```

**Log:**

```
2018-07-18 16:35:18,399 INFO o.a.j.a.JSR223Assertion: The Value is: {=598}
2018-07-18 16:35:18,399 INFO o.a.j.a.JSR223Assertion: It should be: 598
```

any help ?

thanks

Comment: What's the value coming in on `prev.getResponseDataAsString()`?  `{=598}` looks all sorts of wrong 

Comment: the value you are asking is JSON and it is correct,  the problem with data that coming from DB via JDBC result variable "data"

Comment: show us screenshot of your JDBC post-processor configuration and result of its execution

Comment: Could you check which of type `AssessmentId_DB` is? Just the output of `AssessmentId_DB.class`.

Comment: And `valueFromDBQuery.getClass()` might be handy.  And if `AssessmentId_DB.class` is null, can you try `AssessmentId_DB.getClass()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Looking into [Debugging JDBC Sampler Results in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debugging-jdbc-sampler-results-jmeter) article your `data` variable should be an ArrayList of [**HashMaps**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)
2. Looking into `{=598}` my expectation is that your JDBC query is returning a single value
3. Assuming above 2 points I would recommend updating this line:

   ```
   String AssessmentId_DB = valueFromDBQuery[0]
   ```

   to this one:

   ```
   String AssessmentId_DB = valueFromDBQuery[0].find().value as String
   ```

   Groovy's [AbstractMap.find()](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object.html#find()) function basically returns the first element matching the query from the collection, in your case it would be first and the only element.